# Python how to decode windows-874

Tags: python, email, encoding, imap, decoding

A Robot I made crashes because of the following error, can you please advise

```
 29%|███████████████████████▋                                                          | 32/111 [00:47<01:56,  1.47s/it]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RobotVP.py", line 5818, in <module>
    GestionBoitePDP.get_mail_deal_with_it(skipgetpasswords = None)
  File "RobotVP.py", line 5566, in get_mail_deal_with_it
    subject = subject.decode(encoding)
LookupError: unknown encoding: windows-874
```

Function call:

```
for response_part in x:
                        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                            msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1].decode(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))
                            varSubject = msg['subject']
                            varFrom = msg['from']
                            datemsg = msg["Date"]

                    senderemail = varFrom
                    subject = varSubject
                    if subject is not None:
                        subject = subject.replace("\r","").replace("\n","")
                        subject, encoding = email.header.decode_header(subject)[0]
                        if (encoding == None):
                            subject = subject
                        else:
                            subject = subject.decode(encoding)
                    print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "IMAP Mail nb:")
                    print(Fore.CYAN + str(self.i))
                    print("subject:",subject)
                    print("senderemail:", senderemail)
                    print("Date:", datemsg)
```

Thanks for your help,

BR,

Ludo

Parse emails, decode all types of email subjects, the robot was ongoing for over 1.5 is crashing on this:

```
 29%|███████████████████████▋                                                          | 32/111 [00:47<01:56,  1.47s/it]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RobotVP.py", line 5818, in <module>
    GestionBoitePDP.get_mail_deal_with_it(skipgetpasswords = None)
  File "RobotVP.py", line 5566, in get_mail_deal_with_it
    subject = subject.decode(encoding)
LookupError: unknown encoding: windows-874
```

This doesn't work either:

```
if (skipgetpasswords == None):
            for self.i in tqdm(range(latest_email_id, oldest_email_id - 1, -1)):
                resp, data = self.m.fetch(str(self.i), "(UID)")
                msg_uid = self.parse_uid(data[0].decode())
                #x = mail[i-1]
                typ, x = self.m.fetch(str(self.i), '(RFC822)')
                xdeleted = False
                status = ""


                for response_part in x:
                    if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                        msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1].decode(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))
                        varSubject = msg['subject']
                        varFrom = msg['from']
                        datemsg = msg["Date"]

                senderemail = varFrom
                subject = varSubject
                if subject is not None:
                    subject = subject.replace("\r","").replace("\n","")
                    subject, encoding = email.header.decode_header(subject)[0]
                    if (encoding == None):
                        subject = subject
                    else:
                        try: 
                            subject = subject.decode(encoding)
                        
                        except NameError: 
                            subject = subject.decode("windows-874")

                        except:
                            subject = subject.decode("windows-874")

                print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "IMAP Mail nb:")
                print(Fore.CYAN + str(self.i))
                print("subject:",subject)
                print("senderemail:", senderemail)
                print("Date:", datemsg)
```

The succint syntaxic script of what is missing to decode "windows-874" would be highly appreciated

Comment: your bot has very fancy indentations

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory. Python doesn't recognize `windows-874` (the value of `encoding`) as an encoding. You can reproduce by simply putting `b'foo'.decode('windows-874')` in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: Try `cp874`, see the docs for more code pages: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: You may need to keep a dictionary of extra aliases for cases like this where the MIME encoding does not match a built-in Python alias.  (It may also be possible to add an alias to the codecs registry, possibly using `codecs.register`)

Comment: The duplicate hints at a workaround. It is really unfortunate that Python still does not support the official IANA name for this code page. The alias known to Python is `"cp874"`.

Comment: As an aside, `message_from_string` is very often the wrong thing to use. If you have a sequence of bytes, use `message_from_bytes`. You probably also want to add `from policy import default` and use `message_from_bytes(response_part[1], policy=default)` to get a modern `email.message.EmailMessage` object instead of the legacy pre-Python 3.3 `Message` object which is clunkier and lacks many useful methods.